# Express Lucene queries into Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I've the following Lucene Query and need to convert it into Solr (v 3.5) query:

```
final String[] terms = splitInputStringOnSpace(input);

for (final String string : terms) {
    booleanQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term(DocumentFieldsConstants.HOLIDAY_FIELD, string)), Occur.MUST);
    booleanQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term(DocumentFieldsConstants.HOLIDAY_FIELD, string)), Occur.MUST);
}

booleanQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term(DocumentFieldsConstants.DESCRIPTION_FIELD, "1")), Occur.SHOULD);

final String[] exactTerms = splitInputStringOnSpace2(input);

for (final String string : exactTerms) 
{
    final WildcardQuery wildcardQuery = new WildcardQuery(new Term(DocumentFieldsConstants.DESCRIPTION_FIELD, string));
    booleanQuery.add(wildcardQuery, Occur.SHOULD);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a little hard to do without knowing the difference between `splitInputStringOnSpace` and `splitInputStringOnSpace2`. In any case, for the first part, assuming `HOLIDAY_FIELD` is named `holiday` in the Solr schema, etc. you should be able to use PHP or whatever your front-end language is to construct a query as follows:

For each `word` in the given string, add `+holiday:word`. (why does this line occur twice in the Java code?)
Then add `description:1`.
Then for each query term with a wildcard (`*` or `?`, add it also - just the way it is, `description:word`.

Make sure to separate all these with a space, and put the whole string in `q=` part of the Solr query.

Finally, why do all this? Why not just print out the final Lucene query? Chances are it'll work out of the box in Solr since the query syntax is very similar.

Comment: How can I learn about this syntax? I search everywhere even here http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax, but cannot find any good info.

Comment: What are you looking for specifically? That page has enough to build off of ... Also check the Lucene query syntax page.

Comment: You might find this page on the [Standard Query Parser](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser) useful.